# Dynanically choose derived class to instantiate – how to take care of memory?

Tags: c++, inheritance, memory-management, memory-leaks, polymorphism

Consider the following setup:

```
struct Base {
    virtual void f() = 0;
    virtual ~Base() {};
};
struct Helper: Base {
    virtual void f() {}
};
struct Derived: public Base {
    Derived(Helper& helper): m_helper(helper) {}
    void f() {}
    Helper& m_helper;
};
```

that I, at the moment, use conditionally using preprocessor:

```
Helper h;
#if condition
    Derived d(h);
#else
    Helper& d(h);
#endif
```

If you wish, `Derived` is a class that enhances `Helper`.

Now, how can I do that dynamically, at best as little error-prone as possible?

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> p = new Helper();
if(condition){
    p = new Derived(*helper);
}
```

won't work, I guess, because on the assignment `p = new Derived`, I will cause deletion of the original `Helper`, won't I?

Of course, I can simply do something like

```
Helper h;
std::optional<Derived> d = condition ? Derived(h) : {};
Base& p = d ? d : h;
```

Or, go fully manually, and do

```
Helper h;
Derived* d = condition ? new Derived(h) : 0;
Base& p = d ? *d : h;
...
if(d) delete d;
```

None of these solutions really pleases me. What is the advisable way?

Comment: "*on the assignment `p = new Derived`, I will cause deletion of the original `Helper`, won't I?*" - yes. Consider using `shared_ptr` instead.

Comment: @JeJo At the moment, the condition is known at compile time. But that necessitates me to produce different binaries, so I want to make it a runtime condition.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Won't that necessitate refactoring `Derived` such that it accepts `shared_ptr<Helper>` instead of `Helper`? Of course, that's possible in principle.

Comment: @Bubaya no, it doesn't.  See the answer I just posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::shared_ptr` instead of `std:unique_ptr`:

```
auto h = std::make_shared<Helper>();
std::shared_ptr<Base> p;
if (condition) {
    p = std::make_shared<Derived>(*h);
} else {
    p = h;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
auto h = std::make_shared<Helper>();
auto p = condition ? std::shared_ptr<Base>(new Derived(*h)) : h;
```

Though, I would suggest sticking with the `std::optional` approach you proposed, as it doesn't rely on dynamic allocation.  However, what you showed won't compile, but this does:

```
Helper h;
std::optional<Derived> d;
if (condition) d.emplace(h);
Base& p = d ? *d : static_cast<Base&>(h);
```

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/9M78dnlCR)

Comment: That casting looks way better than what I came up with.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
auto h = std::make_unique<Helper>();
auto p = condition ? std::unique_ptr<Base>(new Derived(*h)) : std::move(h);
```

But the `std::optional` option you provided looks simpler and without memory allocation.

Comment: I wasn't able to make a `std:optional` example work with `?:`, I would get either. "*error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘Base&’ from an rvalue of type ‘std::optional’*" or "*error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘Base&’ to an rvalue of type ‘Base’*" no matter what I did

Comment: @RemyLebeau It might it be that you have to use `*` on the `optional` and/or cast to `Base&`. With casting, it worked for me.

Comment: `Base& p = d ? d : h;` - ERROR. `Base& p = d ? d.value() : h;` - ERROR. `Base& p = d ? *d : h;` - ERROR. "*and/or cast to `Base&`*" Ah ha: `Base& p = d ? *d : static_cast<Base&>(h);` - OK. Thanks

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ah! I just assumed that the example he provided compiled. Then it gets a bit more messy, but still clear enough and without memory allocation. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

I would refactor the code:

```
Helper h;

if (condition)
{
    Derived d{h};

    the_rest_of_code(d);
}
else
{
    the_rest_of_code(h);
}

// ...

void the_rest_of_code(Base &h)
{
  // ... whatever happens next.
}
```

Possible variations include using a lambda, to keep things confined.

Comment: `the_rest_of_code()` needs to take `Base&` instead of `d&`

Comment: Actually, `Helper &h` will cover all the bases.

Comment: no, because `Helper` is not a base class of `Derived`, so `Derived d{h}; the_rest_of_code(d);` will not compile.  But taking `Base &h` will

Comment: Well, let's make it `Base &` then.